# "Of your lunch boxes" vs "in your lunch boxes"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

When to use the former and when to use the later? And why?

Example:

You never eat the bell peppers **of** your lunch boxes.

You never eat the bell peppers **in** your lunch boxes.

Comment: Why do you think both are OK? When would you use one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The outside **of** the lunch box is pink.

[image]

> The food wraps **in** the lunch box are vegetarian.

[image]

Comment: I think that's a lunch box bag?

Comment: Both would be considered to be lunch boxes, even though the Hello Kitty lunch box has a cloth exterior, it has sold sides.